# drawRect is not drawing over a UI element

Tags: objective-c, drawrect

TL/DR version: I'm trying to draw a line OVER the `UISlider`, not under it.

I'm overriding the `UISlider`'s `drawRect` method in order to draw lines upon it. For some reason, the sliders progress bar overlaps the line I draw, and it appears like so:

[image]

You can BARELY see the marks, hence my need to draw differently. This is the code I wrote to draw said lines:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20);

    for (NSNumber *x in self.lines) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x.floatValue + 175, 45);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x.floatValue + 175, rect.size.height - 50);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

I figured that would work just fine, but nope. So, I did some research on this website, and the conclusion that I can to is like I need to override `layoutSubViews`.

Perfect, so I added `[super layoutSubviews];` right in the beginning on my method;
Like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    ... // all other code
}
```

No help. As you can tell from the code, I'm setting the line color as `[UIColor whiteColor]`, yet it appears so hard to see, even when I override `layoutSubViews`. I would like it to look like this instead:

[image]

**NOTE-** For anyone trying to do this or similar, as rmaddy stated below:

> "Overriding the drawRect: method of a control provided by Apple is a
>   really bad idea. It's fragile and likely to break in some iOS update."

I'm doing this as a quick patch, and it's NOT best practice to do this if you don't need to.

Comment: try to call `[super drawRect:rect];` before your logic

Comment: I don't think you should call that at all inside drawRect. but if you must, call  `setNeedsLayout` to tell the system you want to update this view on the next update cycle. Doing expensive work on drawRect can make this view quite heavy.
In shot: remove the layoutSubviews, if you implement setNeedsLayout, you should try before and after to see the results, since the basic drawing of the view happens in there.

Comment: `[super drawRect:rect];` will draw the default component. If you are drawing over it, you should first call it then add your logic. If you were drawing a new component (from zero), you would not need to call super.

Since you *are* drawing over the default component, you need to call super first =)

Comment: There is another thing also. It might so happen that your lines would be drawn over the white circle. In this case, the only fix i could see is for you yourself draw the entire component. It's much more work but it gives you more freedom.

Comment: FYI - Overriding the `drawRect:` method of a control provided by Apple is a really bad idea. It's fragile and likely to break in some iOS update. A standard widget should only ever be modified by using whatever API it provides. If the widget doesn't support the customization you want, you need to find a replacement that does. Another option would be to put a subview behind the slider view. Either way, don't mess with `UISlider`.

Comment: One last thing, it might be easer if you have an asset of the maximum track (the component name is track i think). According to the documentation, you can change these assets asi you like, just check it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/maximumValueImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just happens so that the drawing you do are behind the minimum and maximum track image view inside UISlider. You can do it so that you create a separate view, say suppose LineView, and then add it to your UISlider, bring this subView to the top most zIndex and do line drawing to this view. See the implementation I have done to get more idea about how you can achieve.

```
@interface LineView: UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *lines;

@end

@implementation LineView

- (void)setLines:(NSArray *)lines
 {
    _lines = lines;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

// disable the touch as UISlider has thumb view as a separate view which actually needs to handle touch events
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    const CGFloat lineWidth = 5;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

    for (NSNumber *x in self.lines) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x.floatValue , self.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x.floatValue + 20, self.bounds.size.height);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}


@end


@interface MySlider : UISlider

  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *lineView;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *lines;

@end

@implementation MySlider

- (void)setLines:(NSArray *)lines
{
  self.lineView.lines = lines;
}

- (NSArray *)lines
{
  return self.lineView.lines;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.lineView = [[LineView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [self addSubview:self.lineView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.lineView];
}

@end
```

And set it from external interface.

```
mySlider.lines = @[@0, @50, @100, @160, @180, @250];
```

And here is the result,

[image]

Comment: This looks like it works perfectly! Thank you. Side note: My `linesArray` is in my `MySlider` and needs to stay there because that is where it gets populated based upon values of its class. (Such as the line center, etc). The code above initializes it in the line class. Do you know how to edit the above code to make the array values equal?

Comment: Just add a property linesArray to LineView, and set it from MySlider class. Override the setter to redraw it again. See my edits.

Answer (score 2):

The UI elements are subviews of your view.  `drawRect` fills in the contents of the view itself, but its subviews draw on top of the view.  If you want to draw *over* the view and its subviews, you'll need to add your own subviews to the slider, or embed the whole slider in a separate parent view, that has its own subviews on top of the slider.

You can see the view hierarchy of the slider in the debugger, using the recursiveDescription method:

```
(lldb) po [slider recursiveDescription]
<UISlider: 0x7fd7e3e43b60; frame = (0 0; 100 100); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd7e3e42460>; value: 0.000000>
   | <UIView: 0x7fd7e7077e20; frame = (16 49; 82 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd7e7077f30>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fd7e70765e0; frame = (-14 0; 96 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd7e7076310>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fd7e7077b40; frame = (2 49; 14 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd7e70767d0>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fd7e3d1d880; frame = (0 34; 31 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd7e3d1d9c0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fd7e3d1d400; frame = (-13 -6.5; 57 43.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd7e3d1ba50>>
```

You can hide and unhide views in the debugger to see which views are responsible for what in the slider.  One of the two point tall views will be the blue bar behind the slider thumb.  The other will be the bar in front of the slider thumb.  The 31x31 image view is the thumb.  Anything you draw with `drawRect:` is going to go into the top level slider view *itself* (in the example, the view with address `0x7fd7e3e43b60`).  Then all the subviews draw on top of that.